# How prove that the range of an rectifiable curve has measure zero?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a rectifiable continuous curve, show that $f[a,b]$ has content zero.

If $f$ is continuous then is integrable so we have that $[a,b]\times f[a,b]$ has content zero for any partition P of $[a,b]$ but how can i show that only The range has measure zero?

Comment: Do you want $n>1?$

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in the comments, you need $n > 1$.

Assuming $n > 1$, to prove that $f[a, b]$ has content zero it suffices to prove that $f[a, b]$ has measure zero, since $[a, b]$ is compact (see here: [Measure zero and compact then content zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595799/measure-zero-and-compact-then-content-zero))

Then a proof that the measure is zero can be found here: [$f[a,b]$ has measure zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2106497/fa-b-has-measure-zero/)